# VBA collect consecutive similar cells in the row

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, similarity

I have a list of non conformities appeared in different time with different products. I need to find out similar problems.
I already made sorting

[image: 1]

Now I need to get new sheet with similar rows with similar values in Product, Non coformity and date.

[image: 2]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LJ5F.png)

To get it I used following code, but not sure that it's correct approach:

```
' Look for similar non conformities >2
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Result"
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim CurrentRow As Long, Lastrow As Long, Lastrow2 As Long, k As Long
    
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("DuplicateRecords") 'Sheet where I have filtered result
    Set ws2 = wb.Sheets("Result") ' Resulting sheet
    CurrentRow = 2
    
    Lastrow = ws.Range("V" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
    For k = CurrentRow To Lastrow
        If ws.Range("G" & CurrentRow).Value2 = ws.Range("G" & CurrentRow + 1).Value2 And _
           ws.Range("V" & CurrentRow).Value2 = ws.Range("V" & CurrentRow + 1).Value2 And _
           ws.Range("T" & CurrentRow).Value2 = ws.Range("T" & CurrentRow + 1).Value2 Then
            Lastrow2 = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            ws2.Range("A" & Lastrow2 + 1).Value2 = ws.Range("A" & CurrentRow).Value2
            ws2.Range("B" & Lastrow2 + 1).Value2 = ws.Range("B" & CurrentRow).Value2
            ws2.Range("C" & Lastrow2 + 1).Value2 = ws.Range("C" & CurrentRow).Value2
            ws2.Range("D" & Lastrow2 + 1).Value2 = ws.Range("D" & CurrentRow).Value2
          
        End If
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
    Next k
```

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables). Please share what's the expected output.

Comment: Please use this [VBA code](https://davetallett26.github.io/excel-markdown.html) to create a Markdown table from Excel and edit it into your question.

Comment: Could you elaborate what your ultimate goal is? What do you expect the array to contain? Is it necessary to have an array, or is a dictionary also okay?

Comment: @FunThomas - my ideal expectation - new sheet with similar rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another non-VBA solution would be to use `Power Query` (aka `Get & Transform`), available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

***M Code***

```
let

//change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"#", Int64.Type}, {"Product", type text}, {"Non Conf", type text}, {"Date", type date}}),

//Group by the columns you want together == Product / Non-conf / Date
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Product", "Non Conf", "Date"}, {

    //Aggregate by ensuring there are duplicates
        {"All", each if Table.RowCount(_) > 1 then _ else null, 
            type table [#"#"=nullable number, Product=nullable text, Non Conf=nullable text, Date=nullable date]}}),

//Remove the original columns
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Product", "Non Conf", "Date"}),

//Expand the grouped columns and remove the empty rows
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "All", {"#", "Product", "Non Conf", "Date"}),
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Expanded All", 
        each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null})))
in
    #"Removed Blank Rows"
```

[image]

***Edit***
 If you ***must*** use `VBA`, here is a routine which, by using Collections, Dictionary and VBA Arrays, should execute quite rapidly -- 5-10 times quicker than referring to the worksheet at each step

```
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'  or make the edits to use late-binding for Dictionary object
Option Explicit
Sub selectDups()
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim Dict As Dictionary, col As Collection
    Dim vKey(0 To 2) As Variant, sKey As String
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, V, W, X
    Dim rSrc As Range, rDest As Range
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
    
    
Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Set to whatever sheet contains your data
With wsSrc
    'Assume range starts in A1 and is four columns wide
    Set rSrc = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(.Rows.Count, 4).End(xlUp))
    vSrc = rSrc 'create array for faster processing
End With

Set Dict = New Dictionary

'Create dictionary where key contains the items to be grouped
' and the contents is a Collection of the #'s
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    For J = 2 To 4
        vKey(J - 2) = vSrc(I, J)
        sKey = Join(vKey, "~")
    Next J
    If Dict.Exists(sKey) Then
        Dict(sKey).Add vSrc(I, 1)
    Else
        Set col = New Collection
            col.Add vSrc(I, 1)
        Dict.Add Key:=sKey, Item:=col
    End If
Next I

'Include only the duplicates
For Each V In Dict.Keys
    If Dict(V).Count = 1 Then Dict.Remove (V)
Next V

'write results next to original table
'could modify code to write results anywhere
Set wsDest = wsSrc
Set rDest = rSrc.Offset(columnoffset:=6)

'Compute number of rows
    I = 0
    For Each V In Dict.Keys
         I = I + Dict(V).Count
    Next V
    
Set rDest = rDest.Resize(rowsize:=I + 1) '+1 for headers
ReDim vRes(0 To I, 1 To 4)

'Headers
    For J = 1 To 4
        vRes(0, J) = vSrc(1, J)
    Next J
    
'Data
    I = 0
    For Each V In Dict.Keys
        X = Split(V, "~")
        For K = 1 To Dict(V).Count
            I = I + 1
            vRes(I, 1) = Dict(V)(K)
            For J = 1 To 3
                vRes(I, J + 1) = X(J - 1)
            Next J
        Next K
    Next V
    
'Write results to the worksheet
With rDest
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .Columns(4).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yyyy"
    .Style = "Output" 'Optional and may not work internationally
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 365 you could achieve this via formula:

```vb
=LET(d,Tabelle1,
u,UNIQUE(DROP(d,,1)),
cnt,HSTACK(u, BYROW(u,LAMBDA(z,
                             COUNTIFS(INDEX(d,,2),INDEX(z,,1),
                                      INDEX(d,,3),INDEX(z,,2),
                                      INDEX(d,,4),INDEX(z,3))))),
FILTER(cnt,INDEX(cnt,,4)>1))
```

[image]

You can insert the formula via VBA and turn the formula into values as well:

```vb
Public Sub insertDuplicates
Dim f As String

f = "=LET(d,Tabelle1," & vbLf & _
"u,UNIQUE(DROP(d,,1))," & vbLf & _
"cnt,HSTACK(u, BYROW(u,LAMBDA(z," & vbLf & _
"                          COUNTIFS(INDEX(d,,2),INDEX(z,,1)," & vbLf & _
"                                   INDEX(d,,3),INDEX(z,,2)," & vbLf & _
"                                   INDEX(d,,4),INDEX(z,3)))))," & vbLf & _
"FILTER(cnt,INDEX(cnt,,4)>1))"

Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Result")

With ws2.Range("A1")
    .CurrentRegion.Clear
    .Formula2 = f
    .CurrentRegion.Value = .CurrentRegion.Value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, nice solution, but unfortunatley doesn't fit for me. I need VBA solution.

Comment: You can insert the formula via VBA - I updated the answer